# How can i show $\prod a_i<1$?

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose we have $a_1>1$ and for $i>1,0<a_i<1$ how can i show that the product of infinite numbers less than 1 and $a_1$ is less than 1?
$$\prod_{i=1}^\infty a_i<1.$$

Comment: This is equivalent to prove that every decreasing sequence has infimum smaller than $1$, which is clearly false.

Answer (score 2):

Let $p_n=42+\frac1n$, $a_1=p_1>1$, and $a_n=\frac{p_n}{p_{n-1}}<1$ for $n>1$. Then $$\prod_{i=1}^\infty a_i=\lim_{n\to\infty}p_n=42.$$

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this is not always true! Let's make things a bit more understandable by taking the log of everything and then multiplying everything with minus one. Your question now becomes:

Suppose we have $b_1 < 0$ and for $i > 1, b_i > 0$. How can I show that

$$\sum_{i = 1}^\infty b_i > 0$$

It is easy to come up with $b_i$ where this does not hold, e.g. $b_i = 2^{-i}$ for $i > 1$ and $b_1 = -10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000$

Answer (score -1):

Well, $$\prod_{i=1}^\infty a_i= a_1 \prod_{i=2}^\infty a_i$$ so you want to prove that 
$\prod_{i=1}^\infty b_i =0$ if $0<b_i<1$. Which is false.

Taking logarithms, that would be equivalent to 
$ \sum_{i=1}^\infty \log b_i  = \sum_{i=1}^\infty c_i = - \infty$ if $c_i<0$. 
Or $\sum_{i=1}^\infty d_i = + \infty$ if $d_i>0$

If you know about convergent series, you know this is false; for example take $d_i=2^{-i}$